# how to execute a jquery plugin in specific part of page by scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need a code to execute a jquery plugin in specific part of page:
for example in middle of page there is a div tag with id Test and in this div a plugin exist that do someting ,now i wanna when the page is loaded nothing happen with this plugin but when user start to scroll down the page and see this div with id Test this plugin start to work !
is there any idea for me?
thanks

Comment: you can use [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/). its a nice plugin that checks when an element is in the viewport to trigger a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

http://ahmadassaf.com/blog/web-development/scripts-plugins/attaching-javascript-listeners-page-scroll-plugins-hints/

Just google "jquery scroll listener" to find more plugins